# Cannot build project: TypeError: imagemin.gifsicle is not a function

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have installed [gulp-imagemin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-imagemin) plugin and setup a task with following settings:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');

gulp.task('default', () =>
    gulp.src('src/images/*')
        .pipe(imagemin([
    imagemin.gifsicle({interlaced: true}),
    imagemin.jpegtran({progressive: true}),
    imagemin.optipng({optimizationLevel: 5}),
    imagemin.svgo({
        plugins: [
            {removeViewBox: true},
            {cleanupIDs: false}
        ]
    })
]))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'))
);
```

During the build I get this message: `TypeError: imagemin.gifsicle is not a function`. Does anyone know why is this happening? Am I missing a dependancy?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install manually I would try to add those in main package.json, under dependencies (or devDependencies) and in js file use it like:

```
const imageminGifsicle = require('imagemin-gifsicle');

gulp.task('default', () =>
    gulp.src('src/images/*')
        .pipe(imagemin([
    imageminGifsicle({interlaced: true}),
```

---

**Previous post:**

Looks like yes, some dependencies are missing. From the gulp-imagemin package.json file we can see that these dependencies are nested under `optionalDependencies`:

```
"optionalDependencies": {
  "imagemin-gifsicle": "^5.2.0",
  "imagemin-jpegtran": "^5.0.2",
  "imagemin-optipng": "^5.2.1",
  "imagemin-svgo": "^6.0.0"
}
```

If these plugins fails to install it doesnt stop `gulp-imagemin` to install. So first try to go to `gulp-imagemin` folder where its package.json sits and run `npm install`.

If that doesnt fix your problem, you can try to install those plugins manualy - `npm install imagemin-gifsicle`.

Comment: Okay, thanks. But do I have to call them then and where? I mean if I install them manually.

Comment: if you `nom install` in `gulp-imagemin` package.json and it works so you can continue as you do now, but if you install in your main package.json, so most likely you should follow their documentation - `const imageminGifsicle = require('imagemin-gifsicle');` https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin-gifsicle etc.

Comment: I am still receiving the following error: `TypeError: imagemin.gifsicle is not a function`, can you please assist? How can I name these dependencies manually?

Comment: Hm.. Sorry, cant advice much here, but I would check if Package manager (`npm update -g npm@latest` or if you use other PM, so other) and `node` are updated. If updating doesnt fix, I would probably try to play with `gulp-imagemin` source code. Like to move those dependencies from `optionalDependencies` to `dependencies` and see for any errors after `npm install`. To install manually in your root package.json I am not totaly sure, but I update my answer with how I would try